# How to convert this to 32 bit architecture ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, 32bit-64bit, cpu-registers

```
    stp     x29, x30, [sp, -48]!

    mov     x29, sp

    str     wzr, [sp, 44]

    bl      __isoc99_scanf
   
    add     x0, x0, :lo12:.LC1 //.LC1 is a function
```

Do not understand how to convert it to ARM assembly for raspberry pi

Comment: That already is AArch64 (aka ARM64) assembly.  Did you mean converting 64-bit ARM asm to something else, i.e. *from* ARM64?  e.g. port it to run on a 32-bit-only RPi?  That's obviously part of an existing function, and doesn't make much sense as just a fragment.  i.e. we don't know where the args for scanf are coming from; that code is just saving the frame pointer and link register, and storing a 32-bit zero.

Comment: Convert it to 32 bit ARM assembly.

Comment: The pi can run in aarch32 or aarch64 it is not specifically aarch64.   is this compiled code? can you not re-compile the higher level code using a different target?  Otherwisethe arm documentation for both instruction sets are on line and you can simply look the instructions up.   aarch32 does not have as many registers so of course it is up to you to solve the calling convention issues and register usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by the presence of `__isoc99_scanf` that this code was written by a C compiler, in which case you can use your compiler to convert your C code into ARM Assembly.